# yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /home/dennis/WebstormProjects/studentsdiscussionforum has failed

Tags: webstorm, create-react-app

I am trying to create a React application using the command create-react-app ., however when I run the command in the WebStorm's terminal I get the following error:

> yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /home/dennis                          /   webstormProjects/studentsdiscussionforum has failed.
>
> error Incorrect integrity when fetching from the cache

Comment: Try running this command before `reate-react-app`: `yarn cache clean`

Comment: i already found the solution but thanks none the less

Comment: @dennis Please post your solution then -- may help others is a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the issue for me was yarn using an outdated, cached version of create-react-app. After running `yarn cache clean` I had no issue running the create-react-app command.